# Error when using Tomcat + JPA + Hibernate

Tags: tomcat, jpa

I m trying to deploy an app on a Tomcat 7. The app is using JPA with Hibernate.
When I m running the app I keep getting the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/amazontestapplcation] threw exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at com.example.service.EMFService.<clinit>(EMFService.java:8)
    at com.example.service.UserHandler.getAllUsers(UserHandler.java:30)
    at com.example.managedbeans.LoginBean.authenticate(LoginBean.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

All the required jars are included in my class path. I read in an forum that a solution might be to copy all the hibernate JPA-related jars in the Tomcat lib folder. However I wouldnt prefer to do that. Still it s weird why Peristence jar cannot be loaded. 
Below you see my pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Is there a chance that I m missing a dependency? Is it a good idea to add the jars int he tomcat lib folder? Anybody has any other idea about how to solve my issue?
Thnx

Comment: The above shows the Maven dependencies of your project, used to compile it. It doesn't tell if these dependencies are in the generated webapp's WEB-INF/lib directory. Check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Hibernate 3, and `javax.persistence.Persistence` class sits in `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar` (yours might be slightly differently named due to newer Hibernate version). Check if you have it in your `WEB-INF/lib`.